# plotly drops grouped legend (by color, by symbol) when converted from ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, legend

I don't quite understand why the legend disappeared when I converted a plot made by `ggplot` to `plotly` using `ggplotly`. The [plotly help page](https://plotly.com/ggplot2/legend/) did not have any information. I don't think their examples even worked properly on that page.
Any help is greatly appreciated!

## Sample data

```r
library(scales)
packageVersion("ggplot2")
#> [1] '3.4.0'
library(plotly)
packageVersion("plotly")
#> [1] '4.10.1'

data <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
  Level = c("Fast","Fast","Fast","Fast",
            "Fast","Fast","Slow","Slow","Slow",
            "Slow","Slow","Slow"),
  Period = c("1Year","3Month","1Year","3Month",
             "1Year","3Month","1Year","3Month",
             "1Year","3Month","1Year","3Month"),
  X = c(0.002,0.002,0.1,0.1,0.9,0.9,
        0.002,0.002,0.1,0.1,0.9,0.9),
  Y = c(1.38,1.29,1.61,1.61,1.74,0.98,
        1.14,0.97,1.09,1.1,0.94,0.58)
)
```

## ggplot2

```r
plt <- ggplot(data = data,
             aes(x = X,
                 y = Y,
                 shape = Period,
                 color = Level)) +
  geom_point(alpha = 0.6, size = 3) +
  labs(x = " ",
       y = "Value") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = number_format(accuracy = 0.1)) +
  guides(color = guide_legend(title = "Level", order = 1),
         shape = guide_legend(title = "Period", order = 2)) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))
plt
```

[image]

## Convert to plotly, legend disappeared

```r
ggplotly(plt, height = 500) %>%
  layout(xaxis = list(autorange = "reversed"))
```

[image]

## Edit

There was an issue with `guides()`. If I removed it, the legend in `ggplotly` showed up

```r
plt2 <- ggplot(data = data,
             aes(x = X,
                 y = Y,
                 shape = Period,
                 color = Level)) +
  geom_point(alpha = 0.6, size = 3) +
  labs(x = " ",
       y = "Value") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = number_format(accuracy = 0.1)) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))
plt2

ggplotly(plt2, height = 500) %>%
  layout(
    xaxis = list(autorange = "reversed"),
    legend = list(
      title = list(text = '(Period, Level)'))
  )
```

[image]

Comment: There was an issue posted on GitHub that had been resolved but for `geom_line` https://github.com/plotly/plotly.R/issues/476

Comment: This happens only when using `guides`. And from inspecting the JSON object via `plotly_json` the issue is that `showlegend` is set to `false` both in the layout and for the traces. Interestingly this does not happen when using the `guide` argument of the scale instead. A related but not reproducible issue was mentioned here: https://github.com/plotly/plotly.R/issues/2212

Comment: When I run your code, the legend is not gone but it is combined into one legend.

Comment: I have the same results as @Quinten using plotly 4.1.0 and ggplot 3.4.0. Which versions are you using?

Comment: @SamR, I am using the same as you!

Comment: @Quinten & @SamR: I am using `plotly 4.10.1` & `ggplot2 3.4.0`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**After OPs Edit:**

Here is a workaround using basic R {plotly} to modify the legend according to @Tung's requirements:

[image: result]

```
library(scales)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
library(data.table)

DT <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
  Level = c("Fast","Fast","Fast","Fast",
            "Fast","Fast","Slow","Slow","Slow",
            "Slow","Slow","Slow"),
  Period = c("1Year","3Month","1Year","3Month",
             "1Year","3Month","1Year","3Month",
             "1Year","3Month","1Year","3Month"),
  X = c(0.002,0.002,0.1,0.1,0.9,0.9,
        0.002,0.002,0.1,0.1,0.9,0.9),
  Y = c(1.38,1.29,1.61,1.61,1.74,0.98,
        1.14,0.97,1.09,1.1,0.94,0.58)
)

setDT(DT)

LevelDT <- unique(DT, by = "Level")
PeriodDT <- unique(DT, by = "Period")
LevelDT[, Y := min(DT$Y)-1]
PeriodDT[, Y := min(DT$Y)-1]

plt2 <- ggplot(data = DT,
               aes(x = X,
                   y = Y,
                   shape = Period,
                   color = Level)) +
  geom_point(alpha = 0.6, size = 3) +
  labs(x = " ",
       y = "Value") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = number_format(accuracy = 0.1)) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))
plt2

markercolors <- hue_pal()(2)

ggplotly(plt2, height = 500) |>
  layout(
    xaxis = list(autorange = "reversed"),
    legend = list(
      title = list(text = ''),
      itemclick = FALSE,
      itemdoubleclick = FALSE,
      groupclick = FALSE
    )
  ) |>
  add_trace(
    data = LevelDT,
    x = ~ X,
    y = ~ Y,
    inherit = FALSE,
    type = "scatter",
    mode = "markers",
    marker = list(
      color = markercolors,
      size = 14,
      opacity = 0.6,
      symbol = "circle"
    ),
    name = ~ Level,
    legendgroup = "Level",
    legendgrouptitle = list(text = "Level")
  ) |>
  add_trace(
    data = PeriodDT,
    x = ~ X,
    y = ~ Y,
    inherit = FALSE,
    type = "scatter",
    mode = "markers",
    marker = list(
      color = "darkgrey",
      size = 14,
      opacity = 0.6,
      symbol = c("circle", "triangle-up")
    ),
    name = ~Period,
    legendgroup = "Period",
    legendgrouptitle = list(text = "Period")
  ) |> style(showlegend = FALSE, traces = 1:4)
```

PS: [Here](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/5099) the related plotly.js GitHub issue can be found.

---

**Original answer:**

I'm not sure why they are set to `FALSE` in the first place, but setting `showlegend = TRUE` in `layout()` **and** `style()` (for the traces) brings back the legend:

```
library(scales)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

data <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
  Level = c("Fast","Fast","Fast","Fast",
            "Fast","Fast","Slow","Slow","Slow",
            "Slow","Slow","Slow"),
  Period = c("1Year","3Month","1Year","3Month",
             "1Year","3Month","1Year","3Month",
             "1Year","3Month","1Year","3Month"),
  X = c(0.002,0.002,0.1,0.1,0.9,0.9,
        0.002,0.002,0.1,0.1,0.9,0.9),
  Y = c(1.38,1.29,1.61,1.61,1.74,0.98,
        1.14,0.97,1.09,1.1,0.94,0.58)
)

# ggplot2
plt <- ggplot(data = data,
              aes(x = X,
                  y = Y,
                  shape = Period,
                  color = Level)) +
  geom_point(alpha = 0.6, size = 3) +
  labs(x = " ",
       y = "Value") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = number_format(accuracy = 0.1)) +
  guides(color = guide_legend(title = "Period", order = 1),
         shape = guide_legend(title = "", order = 2)) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))
plt

# Convert to plotly, legend disappeared
fig <- ggplotly(plt, height = 500) %>%
  layout(showlegend = TRUE, xaxis = list(autorange = "reversed")) %>%
  style(showlegend = TRUE)
fig
```

[image: result]

Comment: Saw that you commented on my comment on Github. FYI: The issue is a bug introduced in plotly 4.10.1. Proposed a PR to fix tha: https://github.com/plotly/plotly.R/pull/2234

Comment: Thank you both! @ismirsehregal: the legend in plotly is different now. Is there a way to reproduce `ggplot2` legend? See my update

Answer (score 3):

This answer is for `plotly 4.10.1`. I have defined two functions:

1. `set_legend_names()` This edits the names of the `htmlwidget` created by `ggplotly()`, before it is passed to `plotly.js`.
2. `set_legend_symbols()`.  This appends some js to the `htmlwidget` object to change the symbols after `plotly.js` has drawn them.

```r
plt2  |>
    ggplotly(height = 500)  |>
    layout(xaxis = list(autorange = "reversed")) |>
    set_legend_names() |>
    set_legend_symbols()
```

[image]

Function definitions:

#### 1. `set_legend_names()`

```r
set_legend_names <- function(p,
                             new_legend_names = c(
                                 "Fast", "Slow", "One Year", "Three Month"
                             )) {

    # Update legend names and put in one group
    for (i in seq_along(p$x$data)) {
        p$x$data[[i]]$name <- new_legend_names[i]
    }

    p$x$layout$legend$title <- ""

    return(p)
}
```

### 2. `set_legend_symbols()`

```r
set_legend_symbols <- function(p,
                               symbol_nums_change_color = c(3, 4),
                               new_color_string = "rgb(105, 105, 105)",
                               symbols_num_change_shape = 3,
                               symbols_nums_target_shape = 1) {
    js_get_legend <- htmltools::HTML(
        'let legend = document.querySelector(".scrollbox");
        let symbols = legend.getElementsByClassName("legendsymbols");
        const re = new RegExp("fill: rgb.+;", "i");\n
        '
    )

    js_symbol_const <- paste0(
        'const shape_re = new RegExp(\'d=".*?"\');\n',
        "const correct_shape = symbols[",
        symbols_nums_target_shape,
        "].innerHTML.match(shape_re)[0];\n"
    )

    # subtract 1 for 0-indexed js
    change_symbol_color_code <- lapply(
        symbol_nums_change_color - 1,
        \(i)
        paste0(
            "symbols[", i, "].innerHTML = ",
            "symbols[", i, "].innerHTML.replace(re,",
            ' "fill: ', new_color_string, ';");'
        )
    ) |>
        paste(collapse = "\n")

    # subtract 1 for 0-indexed js
    change_symbols_shape_code <- lapply(
        symbols_num_change_shape - 1,
        \(i)
        paste0(
            "symbols[", i, "].innerHTML = symbols[",
            symbols_nums_target_shape, "].innerHTML.replace(shape_re, correct_shape);"
        )
    ) |>
        paste(collapse = "\n")


    all_js <- htmltools::HTML(
        unlist(c(
            js_get_legend,
            js_symbol_const,
            change_symbols_shape_code,
            change_symbol_color_code
        ))
    )

    # Add it to the plot
    p <- htmlwidgets::prependContent(
        p,
        htmlwidgets::onStaticRenderComplete(all_js)
    )

    return(p)
}
```

I've never posted a second answer before but it seems substantially different in `plotly 4.10.1`. I eagerly anticipate the release of `plotly 4.10.2` so I can post a third answer.

Comment: Nice solution! I guess the second answer is the result of OP asking a second question - no legend / modify legend.

Answer (score 2):

### Plotly generates a different legend from `ggplot2` - this can be fixed with R and and a little javascript

The first thing to do is ensure that you have a reasonably current version of the packages:

```r
packageVersion("ggplot2") # 3.4.0
packageVersion("plotly") # 4.10.0
```

With these versions, like @Quentin, I do get a legend, although it is different to the one generated by `ggplot2`.

```r
ggplotly(plt, height = 500) %>%
    layout(xaxis = list(autorange = "reversed"))
```

[image]

### Steps to replicate the `ggplot2` legend:

1. Change the legend text. This can be done by editing the R object before it is passed to `plotly.js`.
2. Remove the color from the `shape` guide. This can only be done with javascript after the plot has rendered.
3. Change the third circle into a triangle. This also needs to be done in javascript.

### Changing the legend text

To do this manually, we could do `p$x$data[[1]]$name <- "Fast"`, and replicate for each layer.

Fortunately, you have manually specified the legend order, making it easy to know where to access the correct legend names before passing to `plotly`. If we just do this step, it will create a legend which looks like this, i.e. still wrong (the first triangle should be a circle and neither should be have a color):

[image]

### Changing the symbol shape and colors

We cannot do this in R. I have written an R helper function to generate some javascript to do this for us:

```r
get_symbol_change_js <- function(symbol_nums,
                                 new_color_string = "rgb(105, 105, 105)") {
    js_get_legend <- htmltools::HTML(
        'let legend = document.querySelector(".scrollbox");
        let symbols = legend.getElementsByClassName("legendsymbols");
        const re = new RegExp("fill: rgb.+;", "i");
        '
    )

    change_symbol_color_code <- lapply(
        symbol_nums,
        \(i)
        paste0(
            "symbols[", i, "].innerHTML = ",
            "symbols[", i, "].innerHTML.replace(re,",
            ' "fill: ', new_color_string, ';");'
        )
    ) |>
        paste(collapse = "\n")


    # shape to change
    shape_change_num <- symbol_nums[1]

    # shape to replace with
    shape_change_from <- shape_change_num - 1

    change_symbols_shape_code <- paste0(
        'const shape_re = new RegExp(\'d=".*?"\');\n',
        "const correct_shape = symbols[", shape_change_from, "].innerHTML.match(shape_re)[0];\n",
        "symbols[2].innerHTML = symbols[", shape_change_num, "].innerHTML.replace(shape_re, correct_shape);"
    )

    all_js <- htmltools::HTML(
        unlist(c(
            js_get_legend,
            change_symbol_color_code,
            change_symbols_shape_code
        ))
    )
    return(all_js)
}
```

We can put this all together to generate the plot as desired:

```r
draw_plotly_with_legend(plt)
```

[image]

### Final `draw_plotly_with_legend()` function

Note this function calls `get_symbol_change_js()`, as defined above. It also uses [`htmlwidgets::prependContent()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/htmlwidgets/versions/1.6.0/topics/prependContent) to attach our custom html to the widget before rendering.

```r
draw_plotly_with_legend <- function(gg = plt,
                                    guide_types = c("colour", "shape")) {

    # Period, Level
    legend_categories <- lapply(
        guide_types, \(x) rlang::quo_get_expr(plt$mapping[[x]])
    )

    new_legend_names <- lapply(legend_categories, \(category) {
        unique(data[[category]])
    }) |> setNames(guide_types)

    # Work out which symbols need to have color removed
    symbols_to_remove_color <- new_legend_names[
        names(new_legend_names) != "colour"
    ] |> unlist()

    new_legend_names <- unlist(new_legend_names)

    symbol_num_remove_color <- which(
        new_legend_names %in% symbols_to_remove_color
    )

    # Create plot
    p <- ggplotly(gg, height = 500) %>%
        layout(xaxis = list(autorange = "reversed"))

    # Show legend
    p$x$layout$showlegend <- TRUE

    # Update legend names and put in one group
    for (i in seq_along(p$x$data)) {
        p$x$data[[i]]$name <- new_legend_names[i]
        p$x$data[[1]]$legendgroup <- "Grouped legend"
    }

    # Get the js code to change legend color

    # js is 0 indexed
    js_symbol_nums <- symbol_num_remove_color - 1
    js_code <- get_symbol_change_js(js_symbol_nums)

    # Add it to the plot
    p <- htmlwidgets::prependContent(
        p,
        htmlwidgets::onStaticRenderComplete(js_code)
    )

    return(p)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for debugging! Looks like there was a bug in [`plotly 4.10.1`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75365694/plotly-did-not-show-legend-when-converted-from-ggplot#comment133046384_75397117) as stefan mentioned in a comment. Is it possible to reproduce `ggplot2` legend? Please see my update

Comment: @Tung it's quite different so I've posted a different answer