# Creating multiple Functional Legends from ggplotly if aesthetic is determined by input

Tags: r, shiny, plotly, ggplotly

Goal: I am trying to create 2 functional and interactive legends using ggplotly.

From reading various documentation, it seems like creating 2 separate legends when you have multiple aesthetics in ggplotly is especially difficult. Many of these posts are from a few years ago and the work arounds are either very complex or some users said it is not yet possible with ggplotly. I am wondering if there is a modern day solution. Additionally, one of my aesthetics is determined by a user input as I am using R shiny so the solution has to be dynamic.

Here is my Code:

```
#Creating the Dataframe
Priority <- c("High","High","Low","Medium","Low")
Days_Until_Due <- c(30, 28, 5, 15, 1)
Subject <- c("History", "English","English","Math","History")
Assignment_ID <- c("hs12","eng23","en25","mat7","hs33")
Progress <- c("Started","Not Started","Started","Finished","Not Started")

df <- data.frame(Priority, Days_Until_Due, Subject, Assignment_ID, Progress)

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

ui = shinyUI(
    fluidPage(
        sidebarLayout(
          selectInput("filter", "Filter", choices = c("Priority","Subject","Progress"), selected = "Priority"),
          plotlyOutput("scatplot")
        )
    )
)
server = function(input, output, session) {
    
  output$scatplot <- renderPlotly({

    #Creating the Text Labels
    df$labelz <- paste("ID:", df$Assignment_ID,
                           "<br>",
                           "Days Until Due:", df$Days_Until_Due)
    #Graph
    agenda <- df %>%
      ggplot(data = ., aes(x= Assignment_ID, y=Days_Until_Due, text=labelz)) + 
      geom_point(aes(shape=Progress, colour=!!sym(input$filter))) +
      xlab("Assignment") + ylab("Days Until Due") 
    
    ggplotly(agenda, tooltip = "text")
  })
    
}
shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Currently my graph/ legend looks like this: [image]

I would like my legend to look like this and change according to the user's input and be interactive (if possible):

[image]

Right now the Shape aesthetic is stagnant but in the future I may want to make that based on a user's input as well (just something to keep in mind).

Thank you in advance, any suggestions or resources are very appreciated :)

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/5099) the related plotly.js GitHub issue can be found.

Comment: This is one of the posts I had seen that was a few years old. They say "we'd love to have it in the library but it's not on anyone's roadmap at the moment". Is there a solution here I am missing or is it still is not possible?

Comment: The issue is still open, accordingly I guess there still is no built-in solution.

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to at least separate the legends even if they aren't interactive? While maintaining the hover text feature?

Comment: Please check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75365694/plotly-did-not-show-legend-when-converted-from-ggplot/75397117#75397117).