ggplotly drops grouped legend (by color, by symbol) when converted from ggplot
I'm trying to use functions (get_symbol_change_js & draw_plotly_with_legend) from this post to avoid a grouped legend when I convert ggplots to ggplotly. But I have this error that I'm not able to solve, could you help me please ?
Error in rlang::quo_get_expr(): ! quo must be a quosure Run rlang::last_trace() to see where the error occurred.
This is what I get if I use ggplotly
This is my ggplot and I expect that my ggplotly looks similar
This is a reproducible example:


library("ggplot2")
library("plotly")
library("ggpubr")

# From: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69289623/avoid-legend-duplication-in-plotly-conversion-from-ggplot-with-facet-wrap
clean_ggplotly_legend <- function(plotly_obj) {
  # Extract legend entries and metadata
  df <- data.frame(
    id = seq_along(plotly_obj$x$data),
    legend_entries = unlist(lapply(plotly_obj$x$data, `[[`, "name"))
  )
  
  # Simplify legend group names (adjust regex if needed)
  df$legend_group <- gsub("^\\((.*?),\\d+\\)", "\\1", df$legend_entries)
  
  # Identify the first entry for each unique group
  df$is_first <- !duplicated(df$legend_group)
  
  # Modify the plotly object
  for (i in df$id) {
    is_first <- df$is_first[[i]]
    plotly_obj$x$data[[i]]$name <- df$legend_group[[i]]  # Assign simplified name
    plotly_obj$x$data[[i]]$legendgroup <- plotly_obj$x$data[[i]]$name  # Group entries
    if (!is_first) plotly_obj$x$data[[i]]$showlegend <- FALSE  # Hide duplicates
  }
  
  # Return the modified plotly object
  return(plotly_obj)
}

# From: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75365694/plotly-drops-grouped-legend-by-color-by-symbol-when-converted-from-ggplot/79222836#79222836
get_symbol_change_js <- function(symbol_nums,
                                 new_color_string = "rgb(105, 105, 105)") {
  js_get_legend <- htmltools::HTML(
    'let legend = document.querySelector(".scrollbox");
        let symbols = legend.getElementsByClassName("legendsymbols");
        const re = new RegExp("fill: rgb.+;", "i");
        '
  )
  
  change_symbol_color_code <- lapply(
    symbol_nums,
    \(i)
    paste0(
      "symbols[", i, "].innerHTML = ",
      "symbols[", i, "].innerHTML.replace(re,",
      ' "fill: ', new_color_string, ';");'
    )
  ) |>
    paste(collapse = "\n")
  
  
  # shape to change
  shape_change_num <- symbol_nums[1]
  
  # shape to replace with
  shape_change_from <- shape_change_num - 1
  
  change_symbols_shape_code <- paste0(
    'const shape_re = new RegExp(\'d=".*?"\');\n',
    "const correct_shape = symbols[", shape_change_from, "].innerHTML.match(shape_re)[0];\n",
    "symbols[2].innerHTML = symbols[", shape_change_num, "].innerHTML.replace(shape_re, correct_shape);"
  )
  
  all_js <- htmltools::HTML(
    unlist(c(
      js_get_legend,
      change_symbol_color_code,
      change_symbols_shape_code
    ))
  )
  return(all_js)
}


draw_plotly_with_legend <- function(gg = plt,
                                    guide_types = c("colour", "shape")) {
  
  # Period, Level
  legend_categories <- lapply(
    guide_types, \(x) rlang::quo_get_expr(plt$mapping[[x]])
  )
  
  new_legend_names <- lapply(legend_categories, \(category) {
    unique(data[[category]])
  }) |> setNames(guide_types)
  
  # Work out which symbols need to have color removed
  symbols_to_remove_color <- new_legend_names[
    names(new_legend_names) != "colour"
  ] |> unlist()
  
  new_legend_names <- unlist(new_legend_names)
  
  symbol_num_remove_color <- which(
    new_legend_names %in% symbols_to_remove_color
  )
  
  # Create plot
  p <- ggplotly(gg, height = 500) %>%
    layout(xaxis = list(autorange = "reversed"))
  
  # Show legend
  p$x$layout$showlegend <- TRUE
  
  # Update legend names and put in one group
  for (i in seq_along(p$x$data)) {
    p$x$data[[i]]$name <- new_legend_names[i]
    p$x$data[[1]]$legendgroup <- "Grouped legend"
  }
  
  # Get the js code to change legend color
  
  # js is 0 indexed
  js_symbol_nums <- symbol_num_remove_color - 1
  js_code <- get_symbol_change_js(js_symbol_nums)
  
  # Add it to the plot
  p <- htmlwidgets::prependContent(
    p,
    htmlwidgets::onStaticRenderComplete(js_code)
  )
  
  return(p)
}




# Very basic chart
p1 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg, colour = factor(cyl), shape = factor(vs) )) +
  geom_point() + theme(legend.position = "none")
p1

p2 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg, colour = factor(cyl), shape = factor(vs) )) +
  geom_point() + theme(legend.position = "none")
p2

p3 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg, colour = factor(cyl), shape = factor(vs) )) +
  geom_point()
p3

ggarrange(p1, p2, p3, ncol = 3, nrow = 1) 

# Dynamic plots
plots <- lapply(list(p1,p2,p3), ggplotly)

# Hide legend in plots 2 and 3
plots[2:3] <- lapply(plots[2:3], function(x) style(x, showlegend = FALSE))

# put legend as ggplot
cleaned_plots <- lapply(plots, clean_ggplotly_legend) # this works in legends with one description

# Plot view
p_plotly <- subplot(cleaned_plots,  nrows=1)

p_plotly # the factor legend disapeard


# Trying draw_plotly with legend
test <- list()
for (i in c(p1,p2,p3)) {
  plt <- i
  draw_plotly_with_legend(plt)
}

# Error in `rlang::quo_get_expr()`:
#   ! `quo` must be a quosure
# Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
# > 



That code doesn't really make sense.  The draw_plotly_with_legend function has an argument gg with default value plt, and then it uses plt instead of gg in the first statement.  There were two different answers given to that question by @SamR.  Did you try the code from the other one?
